# Use loop to Locate Row based on two Criteria and Insert Current Time to 12th Column

Tags: excel

I have userform1 that acts as a login screen to enter in data into a database for each individual.  Userform2 is for logging out.  I am using a loop to match the name and the data in the database.  Once the name and date is found I need to place the current time into an empty column, the farthest column to the right of the dataset.  This is column 12.  I have tried many different combinations and nothing will actually paste the current time, into the appropriate cell.  I have something written incorrectly somewhere but I don't know which part is wrong.  Likely within the 2 criteria (NameOut and DateOut), and/or the insertion of the current time.

```
Private Sub LogOutButton_Click()

Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim NameOut As String
Dim DateOut As String

NameOut = NameOutBox.Text
DateOut = DateOutBox.Text

Sheets("ATDataSheet").Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = NameOut And Cells(i, 2).Value = DateOut Then
        Cells(Columns.Count, 12).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0) = Format(Time, "hh:mm")

        End If

    Next i


Unload Me


Sheets("SignIN").Select

MsgBox "LOG OUT Successful"

End Sub
```

When a person is leaving for the day, they hit a 'Log Out' button which opens userform2.  They enter their name and date and hit the Log Out Button on the userform.  The code will then search through the database and find the name and date, then put the current time in the 12th column of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work because there are no user forms in it. I have commented it nevertheless because there are more problems in it which would surface even after you resolve the presence or absence of a user form.

```
Private Sub LogOutButton_Click()

    Dim finalrow As Integer             ' better to be Long
    Dim i As Integer                    ' better to be Long
    Dim NameOut As String
    Dim DateOut As String

    ' If the following are text boxes on a user form
    ' note that no form has been loaded.
    NameOut = NameOutBox.Text           ' can you avoid typos? What about case?
    DateOut = DateOutBox.Text           ' This isn't a date. It's text that looks like a date.
                                        ' Try not to need the user's injput for this date.
                                        ' It should always be the current date or the date before.

    Sheets("ATDataSheet").Select        ' Don't select anything !!!
    ' Presumably the button is on a sheet. That sheet is the ActiveSheet - no doubt.
    ' If you want to refer to "ATDataSheet", assign it to a variable, e.g.
    ' Dim Ws as worksheet
    ' Set Ws = Worksheets("ATDataSheet")

'    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Ws                             ' refer to the declared worksheet
        finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To finalrow
            ' the next line is highly problematic:
                ' a) the name may not match (different case, wrong spelling)
                ' b) the date may not match (different format, different spelling)
                    ' Try to create a system by which the date is always a true date,
                    ' meaning a number. I think it is created on sign-in. At that time it
                    ' should be the current date and you can enter it without the user's
                    ' asistance, thereby making sure it's a proper date, for example,
                    ' Cells(R, 2)Value = Date
                    ' Then, on the way out, you might check for
                    ' .Cells(i, 2).Formula = Clng(CDate(DateOut))
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = NameOut And .Cells(i, 2).Value = DateOut Then
                ' wrong addressing. you want .Cells(i, 12)
                .Cells(Columns.Count, 12).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0) = Format(Time, "hh:mm")
            End If

        Next i
    End With

    ' Me is the worksheet at this point. No form has been loaded.
    ' The worksheet can' be unloaded.
    Unload Me

    ' I think this is the sheet on which you have the button which
    ' called this procedure. If you didn't select any other sheet,
    ' and you should not, then it is still the ActiveSheet at this point.
    Sheets("SignIN").Select

    MsgBox "LOG OUT Successful"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  The Userform is on the "SignIN" Sheet, which is opened by clicking a button.  When the form opens the user has to enter their name, (a limitation because it must be exactly the same).  I am still struggling with For loop and the IF statement.  I followed your instruction, but could you look over these lines                                                                
     `For i = 2 To finalrow`
         `If .Cells(i, 1).Value = NameOut And .Cells(i, 2).Value = DateOut Then`
            `.Cells(i, 12).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0) = Format(Time, "hh:mm")`

Comment: Use Debug.Print .Cells(i, 2).Value, DateOut, .Cells(i, 2).Value = DateOut, inserted before the IF statement to see what you actually compare and the result of the comparison in the Immediate window. Repeat for the name.